# How to trigger jobs in gitlab-ci on merge request from any branch to develop/master?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to gitlab-ci and I want to launch some scripts on a remote server (i used ssh) depending on the actions made on gitlab. There are 2 scripts :

1. Let's say script A when a merge request is accepted from any branch to `develop` branch ;
2. Then I want to execute script B when a merge request is accepted from any branch to `master` branch.

What I have already tried is to use the `only: [merge_requests]` keyword in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file as suggested [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html) in the doc but it doesn't work, as the job is not triggered.

Here is my file :

```
before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts


build:
   stage: build
   tags:
    - alextag
  only:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - echo "Check if merge_request working here"

test:
  stage: test
  only:
    - branches
  tags:
    - alextag
  script: 
    - sh alex2.sh
    - echo "$USER"
```

The script in the `test`job is working perfectly as every commit/push on the current branch, but when I merge to another branch or develop/master the `build` job is not triggered.

Do you know how to make this functional ? Any help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: @mholle I open and accept a merge request. Once accepted I want to perform the execution of the script

Comment: iirc the script should get executed when opening the MR. Once accepted the job that gets executed on pushes starts for the branch you were merging onto.

Comment: @Leonald, did you find a solution to this? Asking because I'm observing the same issue.

Comment: @IokanaanIokan @Iokanaan Iokan Yess it finally worked for me! The `merge_requests` attribute on jobs was introduced for gitlab server version **11.6** but I was working on gitlab version **11.4**. See [Pipeline for merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for the problem. The version of the Gitlab instance I was working on was **11.4** but the `merge_requests` attribute for jobs was introduced in version **11.6.**
See [Pipeline for merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html) and the [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15310) associated to the feature.

Note that this attribute only triggers the job when the merge request is `created`, not when the merge request is `accepted/merged`. You can use [gitlab api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) to have all the information about merge requests.